# Identifying which form sends the POST method

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have been trying to achieve something so that when I receive the **POST** I know which form sends it

I checked the [form attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms_attributes.asp) and it doesn't seem to be able to have an *ID* or something similar, I can't think of anything functional inside the `router.post()` either and what little I have come up with hasn't worked

This is the form

```html
<form action="/dashboard/" method="POST">
   <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-success">Do!</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

I want to know if the FORM that sends the post is that one.

This is the way I receive the **POST** in its respective .*js* file

```js
router.post("/", async (req, res) => { . . .
```

I have tried testing some things with `req`, without any luck

*As a little relevant information, I'm using Bootstrap 5, I don't have my own styles or classes.*

Comment: If you need to do something different based on which form is being submitted, you would typically just define two different endpoints, one for each form, and not try to tell the submissions apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden input field to the form like

```
<input type="hidden" id="formName" name="formName" value="myDashboardForm">
```

Then access the "formName" inside the POST variables on the Backend.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to include a [hidden input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden)

```
<form action="/dashboard/" method="POST">
   <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-success">Do!</button>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" id="formId" name="formId" value="formType1">
</form>
```

Then you should be able to get the formType in `req.body.formId`

Answer (score -1):

Add the input field to be hidden and acess using the form id

```
<form action="/dashboard/" method="POST">
   <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-success">Do!</button>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" id="formId" name="formId" value="formType1">
</form>
```